# How I can load the Product repository without using the dependency injection?

Tags: magento2.4, command

I made my own command to seed a table:

```php
namespace MageGuide\FirstModule\Console\Command;

use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost;
use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPostResource;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * Seed Multiple Blogposts with Skus
 */
class BlogpostSeeder extends Command
{
    const BLOGPOSTS_NUM=10000;

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setName('db:seed:blogposts')->setDescription('Seed Multiple Blogposts');
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, self::BLOGPOSTS_NUM);

        // select random skus
  
        for($i=self::BLOGPOSTS_NUM;$i>0;$i--){
            $blogPost = ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(BlogPost::class);
            $blogPost->setTitle("BLogpost ".microtime());
            $blogPost->setPost("BLogpost Body".microtime());
            $resource = $blogPost->getResource();
            $resource->save($blogPost);
            $progressBar->advance();
        }


        $output->writeln("Success");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And I want to select random skus and populate it into my Blogpost eg in the `setPost()`. A way to do it is to use the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` class but I want to avoid using the dependency injection.

IS there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectManager to instantiate `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository`, and `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` class objects as you have done with your custom (BlogPost) model.

Example:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

...

$objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
$skuList = ['24-MB01','24-MB04','24-UG01'];

/** @var ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$productRepository = $objectManager->create(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);

/** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $objectManager->get(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
$searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(ProductInterface::SKU, $skuList, 'in');

/** @var ProductSearchResultsInterface $products */
$productList = $productRepository->getList($searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getItems();
```